# Getting value from HTML using C#

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on an inventory management system with barcodes. I've found a website that I can get the barcode information from, it's stored in a href. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
<a href="/ean/BarcodeNumber" target="_blank">ItemName</a>
```

What I need to do is get the item name, store it into a string so I can then update a label. The main problem I'm having issues with is accessing certain HTML tags within my code.

Is there an easy way to get the "ItemName" from a tag?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your current code and define what "having issues" means.

Comment: You need a DOM parser.

Comment: are you familiar with xpath ? you can read the html with something like html-agility-pack and then retriev the element by using an xpath that points to that a-tag

Comment: I second using the HTML Agility pack, it sounds like you are scrapping a website for information, the HTMLAP will allow you to scan through an entire website and pick out certain HTML tags based on simple filters.

Comment: If your lookups are simples (or medium-simple :), you can also just use a WebBrowser class, which will return you a `HtmlDocument` object. Then you can use the standard tools to extract the values you need. E.g., `[HtmlDocument].GetElementsByTagName("A").OfType<HtmlElement>().Where(elm => elm.GetAttribute("href").Contains("BarcodeNumber"));`

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net) via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack):
Simple example with [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
var html = 
@"<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href=""/ean/BarcodeNumber"">My Link Text</a>
  </body>
  </html>";

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    string name = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectSingleNode("//html/body/a[@href='/ean/BarcodeNumber']")
                    .InnerText;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there anyway that I can get it too display the item name ? As currently, the above only displays "My Link Text" and never using Html Agility Pack, I'm clueless on how I'd go about getting the actual item name.I didn't say but this is for a website, so guessing I would change the html too the url of the website as I've just realised it's currently storing html into the variable not getting the website! Duh!

Comment: @KevinGorman I think I don't understand what you actually mean. You don't have the html available in your code or do you need help for getting the html of any website? If so, please ask another question for that specific problem. 
Anyway it would be very helpful if you provide more context and information within your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll start again. I have found a website that offers barcode information, I need too access urls (/?q=Barcode), on that page there is a hred tag that I need to get the HTML inner from, <a href="/ean/Barcode" target="_blank">ItemName</a> (Xpath: /html/body/div[2]/p[3]/b/a). What I need, is a way for c# to get the itemname from any url that I give it. All the URLs are the same just different barcode numbers and items names. Creating the url won't be hard, it's just I don't know how to access the html a href inner text. So all I want would be MessageBox.Show(itemname);

Comment: That's exactly what the example shows. You can use the HtmlAgiltyPack with the code above to get the InnerText of the Link. [Look at this example on .NET Fiddle to see HtmlAgilityPack in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KHzARJ)